# How to solve the problem of the name of file in shell?

Tags: bash

I have got this script in bash

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for file in $*
do
    rm $file
done
```

however, the name of my file can be whatever ex "file*? 2.txt"
when passing this file in the argument line I get an error

Comment: `for file in "$@"`, but `in "$@"` is the default so just `for file` is sufficient. Then `rm "$file"`. [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend.

Comment: `rm -- "$file"` to be extra safe (in case the file name itself starts with a `-`).

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to @Biffen and @chepner for their comments.

In a nutshell, I created the `x.sh` script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

printf '%d args: %s\n' "$#" "$*"
for file in "$@"
do
    rm -- "$file"
done
```

To test it test:

```
$ touch y.txt
$ touch y.foo
$ chmod +x x.sh
$ ./x.sh y*
2 args: y.foo y.txt
```

In case one folder contains also directories:

```
$ touch y.txt
$ mkdir -p y
$ ./x.sh y*
2 args: y y.txt
rm: cannot remove 'y': Is a directory
```

In this case, you need your script to remove also directories recursively, you'd need your `rm` command to include the `-f` (force), `-r` (recursively). e.g.:

```sh
rm -fr -- "$file"
```

Comment: The unquoted expansions make this break for all files with blanks or metacharacters in them.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW. I updated and I think I addressed your comment.

Comment: `for file in $@`  `for file in "$@"`

Comment: missed it. Thanks @AndrejPodzimek. Updated.